# Accessing pivot entries with additional colums in eloquent and result caching

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have been following the laravel relations documentation at:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

I have 'users' and roles' tables. But I have an additional table 'organizations' so my pivot table 'user_role' has a 3rd column. The pivot table columns are 'user_id,role_id,organization_id'.

What I want to do is to give users different roles based on which organization they are attached to. I guess it is a sort of triple-pivot solution.

In my User model I have

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot('organization_id');
}
```

and I am able to access it using for example (organization_id=1)

```
$user->roles()->wherePivot('organization_id',1)->get()->toArray();
```

This runs the SQL query which is great...

```
select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `role_user`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `role_user`.`organization_id` as `pivot_organization_id` from `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role_user`.`user_id` = '1' and `role_user`.`organization_id` = '1'
```

Everything is fine until now. Normally I had a simple function in User model which checked if user had a role.

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
      return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
}
```

For some reason this worked really well. It run a query only once (even though called several times).

Now I have something like this

```
public function hasRole($role, $organization_id)
{
      return $this->roles()->wherePivot('organization_id', $organization_id)->get()->contains('name', $role);
}
```

I see that this makes several of the same query in db now. (the hasRole function is being called few times from a page with same role/company arguments)

Question is, can you tell how can one avoid this situation and get away with a single query? and why is this happening? (I guess it has something to do with accessing through model and query builder?)

Thanks

PS. I have somewhat solved the issue using a filter but the sql query is fetching all rows and does not use the where query. There must be a better way? In hasRole():
    $this->roles->where('pivot.organization_id',$organization_id)->contains('name',$role)

and this runs a query (only once independent of how many times it is called):

```
select `roles`.*, `role_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `role_user`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id`, `role_user`.`organization_id` as `pivot_organization_id` from `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` where `role_user`.`user_id` = '1'
```